# What settings to use to export mysql table rows that I'll be importing to another table with data using phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

If I'm using phpmyadmin to manage mysql database, what settings should I use to export only two rows of data that I'll be importing to another table with the same name that contains many other rows?

I used the quick option, but I'm getting an error that table already exists and nothing gets imported.

If I use the default custom option with the default settings, I get the same error message.

So, what's the best settings to use to export settings that I'm going to import to another table?

Comment: are those tables in different databases?

Comment: these are wordpress databases in two different servers. I'm just trying to transfers settings  for a plugin to the new database. thanks,

Comment: I think I figured out, I ended up opening the .sql dump and I copied the INSERT INTO statement with the data. I pasted into the SQL tab of phpmyadmin, and I ran the query and the data imported successfully. Is this approach OK?

Comment: yes i showed you as answer another posiibilities

Answer (score 1):

You have two possibilities.

1. use the export at the botton of the table, after selecting you data with the correct data

see [image: phpmyadmin picture]

2. use [SELECT INTO OUTfile](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html)

LIKE

```
SELECT a,b,a+b INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.txt'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  FROM test_table WHERE n= 1;
```

Please check the limitations in the link for secure_file_priv

You can after import it via phpmyadmin or use [LOAD DATA Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html)